# How do i create two directory at same time using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mkdir

I am using this npm to create directory

```
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var dest = denotes the path
mkdirp(dest, function (err) {
    if (err) cb(err, dest);
    else cb(null, dest);
});
```

My doubt is how do I create two directory in different path?

I have tried following code:

```
var dest = first path;
var dest2 = second path;
mkdirp(dest,dest2, function (err) {
  if (err) cb(err, dest);
  else cb(null, dest);
});
```

But its not working how do I do that?Also, I need to rename for those folder which is in different path at same time.

*Updated*

```
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var destArray = [ './root/dest1', './dest2' ]
destArray.map( path => {
  mkdirp(path, function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
    else {
    res.json("ok")
      }
  });
})
```

I have used this solution, Because of loop am getting can't set headers again

Comment: The documentations says `usage: mkdirp [DIR1,DIR2..] {OPTIONS}`. Try `mkdirp( [dest, dest2] , err => ...)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try this

Comment: No its throwing error like path must be a string [ './public/uploads/docs/Vishnu T',
  './public/uploads/inspection/Vishnu T' ]

Comment: Show real code `var dest = first path;` is not real code for instance

Comment: var dest =  './public/uploads/docs/Vishnu T';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var destArray = [ './root/dest1', './dest2' ]
destArray.forEach( path => {
  mkdirp(path, function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
    else console.log('Directory created: ' + path )
  });
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually am sending json data..So When i am going to create a next path am getting can't set headers error

Comment: Why `.map`? It should be `forEach`

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, we can use forEach as well

Comment: Well in this case, you _should_ use `.forEach` and not `.map` because `.map` is supposed to apply a function to each element in the array and _return_ it, creating a new array, which `.forEach` does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following code

```
const fs = require('fs');
const {promisify} = require('util');
const mkdir = promisify(fs.mkdir);

const destArray = [ 'dest1', 'dest2'];

Promise.all(destArray.map(destPath => mkdir(destPath))).
   then(res => {
       console.log('Directories created');
   }).
   catch(err => {
       console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: can I able to set headers here

Comment: @Vishnu what do you imply by setting headers?

Comment: like req.flash('add', 'Client added successfully.');

Comment: yes you can send it .Inside the then and catch block respectively